# Handling Decimal values from database in python

Tags: python, python-2.7

I'm trying to fetch some data from the database and trying to write it into a csv file. The data contains some of the decimal values and my results are like below:

```
Decimal('28.00'), Decimal('124.00'), Decimal('11.14'), Decimal('16.00'), Decimal('38.00'),
```

How do I get rid of all those "Decimal" things?

Comment: Could you provide the code you're using to output the data to the CSV file?

Comment: How are you getting these [``decimal.Decimal``](https://docs.python.org/2/library/decimal.html#decimal-objects) objects in the first place?

Comment: If you're using the normal `csv` module interface (e.g., via the `writerow` method), you shouldn't be seeing those `Decimal` strings in the output CSV file in the first place.  What method are you using to write the data to the CSV file?

Comment: I just did a "select * from table" and printed the output on  my screen using  pyodbc. The data contains lots of decimal values and becoz of that when i print the result i get the output like i mentioned above. Any suggestion to get the data with out these "Decimal" keyword.

Answer (score 0):

[`map()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html) them to [`float()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#float):

**Example:**

```
>>> from decimal import Decimal
>>> xs = [Decimal('28.00'), Decimal('124.00'), Decimal('11.14'), Decimal('16.00'), Decimal('38.00')]
>>> map(float, xs)
[28.0, 124.0, 11.14, 16.0, 38.0]
```

Or individually (*perhaps in a loop*):

```
>>> from decimal import Decimal
>>> x = Decimal('28.00')
>>> float(x)
28.0
```

See: [decimal](https://docs.python.org/2/library/decimal.html)

*`decimal.Decimal` implements the `__float__` special method so `Decimal` objects can be coeced into floats using the `float()` constructor*

Comment: This shouldn't be necessary, though (and is potentially harmful, since it could lose information).  The `writerow` method on a CSV writer should automatically output the `str` of a `Decimal` instance, which doesn't include the "Decimal" wrapper.  It's not clear how the OP is getting `Decimal` strings in the CSV file.

Comment: No I know; if the OP would [Edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/30484626/edit) the question to clarify I'd be more than happy to oblige!

Comment: I saw these "Decimal" things even if i used writerow. but it worked fine after using writerows.